# Image path passed into `src` but image does not display.

Tags: html, css, image

In the following html block I passed the image into the `src` attribute in multiple different ways, but the images do not display.

```
<article class="eventlist-event eventlist-event--upcoming eventlist-event--hasimg eventlist-hasimg eventlist-event--multiday"><a class="eventlist-column-thumbnail content-fill" href="">
    <img class="eventlist-thumbnail" data-src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/46/Lockheed_Martin_F-22A_Raptor_JSOH.jpg" data-image="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/46/Lockheed_Martin_F-22A_Raptor_JSOH.jpg" src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/46/Lockheed_Martin_F-22A_Raptor_JSOH.jpg">
</a>
    <a class="eventlist-column-date" href="">
        <div class="eventlist-datetag">
            <div class="eventlist-datetag-inner">
                <div class="eventlist-datetag-startdate eventlist-datetag-startdate--month">January</div>
                <div class="eventlist-datetag-enddate">2017</div>
                <div class="eventlist-datetag-status"></div>
            </div>
        </div></a>
<div class="eventlist-column-info">
    <h1 class="eventlist-title"><a class="eventlist-title-link" href="">Deep Reinforcement Learning for Dialogue Generation </a></h1>
    <p><font color="gray" font-family="squarespace-ui-font" font-weight="100">This is the abstract of the project ipso facto. </font></p>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</article>
```

Is there anything I am missing here?

Comment: Images are loading fine for me. Maybe issue where the request is blocked. Just check that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/46/Lockheed_Martin_F-22A_Raptor_JSOH.jpg"`

Looks like you've got some whitespaces, have you tried `src="https:...`?

It doesn't appear to be problematic [here](https://jsfiddle.net/2ukehmck/2/), but depending on your view engine/src code it might be affected differently.

Comment: yup same result.

Comment: As tej mentioned, it might be an issue with your server code then. When you open up your web console and refresh, do you get any errors?

Comment: ok when I render the file by itself it renders now. The issue it's actually included as part of a larger template, so the problem might be at the parent level. Very strange that such a thing would happen though ...

Comment: It's not actually as strange as you might think. Your particular file seems to be conflicting with either how you're including your partials, or again, the source code. If you are still having trouble, can you add in the parent template, as well as any relevant scripts being executed in the html?